# Error CS0120 in Unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Stealth tutorial on Unity5. While I was writing the "Alarm Light" script, this error showed up

> Assets/AlarmLight.cs(28,31): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Light.intensity'

Here is the entire script;

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class AlarmLight : MonoBehaviour {

    public float fadeSpeed = 2f;
    public float highIntensity = 2f;
    public float lowIntensity = 0.5f;
    public float changeMargin = 0.2f;
    public bool alarmOn;


    private float targetIntensity;

    void Awake(){
        GetComponent<Light>().intensity = 0f;
        targetIntensity = highIntensity;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (alarmOn) {
            GetComponent<Light>().intensity = Mathf.Lerp (GetComponent<Light>().intensity, targetIntensity, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
            CheckTargetIntensity ();
        }
        else
            {
            Light.intensity = Mathf.Lerp (GetComponent<Light>().intensity, 0f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        }



    void CheckTargetIntensity (){
        if (Mathf.Abs (targetIntensity - GetComponent<Light>().intensity) < changeMargin) {
            if (targetIntensity == highIntensity) {
                targetIntensity = lowIntensity;
            }
            else {
                targetIntensity = highIntensity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In `Update()`, you have `Light.intensity = …`. Should that be `GetComponent<Light>().intensity = …` instead?

Comment: Please pay attention when you choose a tag, The [tag:unity] tag states in its excerpt *don't use this tag for the Unity3d game engine*

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what the compiler is telling you is that you're trying to use an instance member like a static member, which obviously, is incorrect.

Look at this line in your code

```
 else {
     Light.intensity = Mathf.Lerp (GetComponent<Light>().intensity, 0f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

On the right hand side, you use `GetComponent<Light>().intensity`, which is the correct way of accessing a single Light's intensity.

On the LEFT hand side, however, you're using `Light.intensity`. The `Light` class does not have any static member named `intensity`, and hence the error.

Change your code to

```
else {
    GetComponent<Light>().intensity = Mathf.Lerp (GetComponent<Light>().intensity, 0f, fadeSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

and your error should go away.

Think about it this way. You can change the intensity of each of your lights seperately, correct? Therefore, it MUST be a member of an instance of the class, rather than the class itself.

If changing a single value effects everything that uses it, (such as Physics.gravity), then those are static members of the class. Keep that in mind, and you won't have this issue pop up.

Comment: Yeah it went away! Thank you so much, I appreciate your detailed answer!

Comment: please accept the answer so people know your problem got solved